# How to get the correct signatures order of annotations in methods when performing overriding

Tags: python-3.6, mypy

I am trying to fix some methods annotations on magic and normal methods. For example, I have some cases like:

```

```
class Headers(typing.Mapping[str, str]):
    ...

    def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
        ...
        return False

    def keys(self) -> typing.List[str]:
        ...
        return ['a', 'b']
```

```

and when I run `mypy somefile.py --disallow-untyped-defs` I have the following errors:

`error: Argument 1 of "__contains__" incompatible with supertype "Mapping"
error: Argument 1 of "__contains__" incompatible with supertype "Container"
error: Return type of "keys" incompatible with supertype "Mapping"`

What I understand is that I need to override the methods using the `@override` decorator and I need to respect the order of inheritance. Is it correct?

If my assumption is correct, Is there any place in which I can find the exact signatures of the parent classes?

Answer (score 2):

After asking the question on `mypy`, the answer was:

> Subclassing `typing.Mapping[str, str]`, I'd assume that the function
>   signature for the argument key in **contains** ought to match the
>   generic type?

**contains** isn't a generic method -- it's defined to have the type signature **contains**(self, key: object) -> bool. You can check this on [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L335). The reason why **contains** is defined this way is because doing things like 1 in {"foo": "bar"} is technically legal.

> Subclassing def **contains**(self, key) to def **contains**(self, key:
>   str) is in any case more specific. A more specific subtype doesn't
>   violate Liskov, no?

When you're overriding a function, it's ok to make the argument types more general and the return types more specific. That is, the argument types should be contravariant and the return types covariant.

If we did not follow the rule, we could end up introducing bugs in our code. For example:

```
class Parent:
    def foo(self, x: object) -> None: ...

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self, x: str) -> None: ...

def test(x: Parent) -> None:
    x.foo(300)  # Safe if 'x' is actually a Parent, not safe if `x` is actually a Child.

test(Child())
```

Because we broke liskov, passing in an instance of Child into test ended up introducing a bug.

Basically if I use `Any` for `key` on `__contains__` method is correct and `mypy` won't complaint :

```
 def __contains__(self, key: typing.Any) -> bool:
    ...
    return False
```

You can follow the conversation [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5633)